# Delphi: Exception on proccess insert Blob field in table MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi

At an insert in the table of files of the sizes > 16Mb outside local network, get exception:

[image: Exception insert Blob field]

in local network no problem At an insert in the table of files of the sizes > 16Mb!

Code insert blob:

```
     procedure TQueryThread.Execute;
begin
  FMyConn := TMyConnection.Create(nil);
  FMyConn.Server := IniParams.pServer;
  FMyConn.Port := StrToInt(IniParams.pPort);
  FMyConn.Database := IniParams.pDatabase;
  FMyConn.Username := 'addressbook';
  FMyConn.Password := 'su7Qcatw';
  FMyConn.Connected := true;
  qFileBlob := TMyQuery.Create(nil);
  qFileBlob.Connection := FMyConn;
  qFileBlob.SQL.Clear;
  qFileBlob.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO attachment (address_id,file_blob,create_date,file_name,file_extension,description) values (:pAddressID,:pFileBlob,:pCreateDate,:pFileName,:pFileExtension,:pDescription)');
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pAddressID').AsInteger := FAddressID;
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileBlob').LoadFromFile(FName, ftBlob);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pCreateDate').AsDate := FCreateDate;
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileName').AsString := ExtractFileName(FName);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pFileExtension').AsString := ExtractFileExt(FName);
  qFileBlob.ParamByName('pDescription').AsString := FDescription;
  qFileBlob.Execute;
  Synchronize(DisplayMessage);
end;

    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
    mysql> show variables like "max_allowed_pa
    -> ;
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 524288000 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: That's SQL syntax error , also check `Constraints` in your table

Comment: @Sami:  What syntax error are you referring to?

Comment: @MartynA: The one in the image of the exception dialog.

Comment: That's not how you deal with BLOB fields. Search this site for *[delphi] tblobfield*, as there are existing posts that will show you the proper way.